# Travis emulator stop after android-wait-for-emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci

Hi I have the next travis configuration:

language: android

```
env:
  global:
  - JAVA8_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
  - TERM=dumb

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

android:
  components:
   - platform-tools
   - tools
   - build-tools-23.0.1
   - build-tools-22.0.1
   - android-23
   - android-22
   - extra
   - extra-android-support
   - extra-google-google_play_services
   - extra-google-m2repository
   - extra-android-m2repository
   - addon-google_apis-google-23
   - addon-google_apis-google-22

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force --name test --target android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -no-boot-anim &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &

script:
  - ./gradlew :projectcore:checkstyle
  - ./gradlew clean build -x lint
  - ./gradlew :project:connectedAndroidTest
```

Ok, if I run this one, download all dependencies, but when run the emulator stop it.

```
emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -no-boot-anim &
$ android-wait-for-emulator
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Failed to Initialize backend EGL display
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
```

I don't know what it's the problem :S, somebody have any clue about the problem? If I remove android-wait-for-emulator continue the execution but test fails because emulator is not attached yet (have sense).
Ideas?

Comment: Either the emulator didn't spin up or it requires human interaction.

Comment: I found the problem, I've created my own script for debug wait for emulator and I found this problem ./script/my-wait-emulator.sh: line 11: adb: command not found

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem: when trying to install `platform-tools`, Travis fails to move a folder because the folder exists and removes the folder content, this folder is `platforms-tools`, which contains the `adb` command, which explains why `android-wait-for-emulator` fails.

The solution is removing `- platform-tools` and `- tools` from the **components** section, because are already provided by default.

Fixing this one has been hard, I trust that this could be useful for anyone.

Comment: However, the official doc recommends adding existing components - `we recommend that you explicitly specify the required components for your project`: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/